# how to create folder in sharepoint using SSIS

Tags: sharepoint-2007, ssis, sharepoint-designer

Need Help!!!!
I need to load data into sharepoint from Oracle Table using SSIS.
Here Table contains Customer Information.
I have to create CustomerID as Folder and within the Folder need to load perticular Customer Details

How do i buld the Package for this.

Note: I follwed the below link, But in that example they are not explained how to create Folder. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd365137(SQL.100).aspx

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a document library, then you can create the folder by using the path to the document library.  If you need to know the path, then go to the document lirbary -> actions -> Open in Windows Explorer.  This Windows Explorer window will have the path and it responds to SSIS directory create commands.